# White line when finish class col bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.1 and bootstrap4-fullscreen-modal (https://github.com/basilebong/bootstrap4-fullscreen-modal).

I have written a html page with bootstrap and the browser shows it very well.

But when I import this page on the bootstrap4-fullscreen-modal using

```
$("#idCl").load("page.html");
```

the modal properly works but I see this:[image].

The page is composed in this way:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Main container -->
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-sm-5">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2" id="id1">
            </div>
           <!-- Here there is the problem -->
            <div class="col-sm-5" id="id2">
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is when the `id1` div finishes and start with `id2` div.

In addition, I have noted this: on chrome there is this problem, on safari the problem doesn't appear.

Have you a solution?

I have tried to zoom or reduce zoom but I see the white line only when I'm on "normal view" (100%).

The modal code is:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen force-fullscreen" id="idClxViewCardModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="idCl">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Try inspector of the browser and see if any of them has a margin.

Comment: But when I don't import the page on the modal, this white line doesn't appear. I have tried to zoom in this condition but nothing. But when I import into the modal I see this white blank.

Comment: I have checked but the padding and margin are zero

Comment: Is `page.html` a full HTML document, including doctype, head, body ...? Then you should not try to stuff that into an HTML element on another page to begin with. Go read up on how to get `.load` to only insert a specific portion of the loaded document.

Comment: page.html is a normal page, but it has been done in order to be imported in another page. In fact in other situation it properly works.

Comment: I have noted this: on chrome there is this problem, on safari the problem doesn't appear.

Comment: _"page.html is a normal page"_ - so a _full_ HTML document, yes or no? _"but it has been done in order to be imported in another page."_ - it doesn't matter what you "made it for", it matters what it actually contains.

Comment: I have tried in the both case: completed and no-completed.

Comment: Might be a sub-pixel rounding issue.

Comment: I have discovered the cause I have created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109459/gradient-in-full-screen-modal-bootstrap